# Program runs in CLion but gives procedure entry point error when run from file explorer

Tags: c++, clion

I have been writing a project in C++ using CLion. The program runs perfectly in CLion's console, but when I try to run the program from File Explorer, I get the following error message:

```
The procedure entry point _ZSt28_throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\Users\anike\Desktop\emulator\8085-cpp\cmake-build-debug\808
5_cpp.exe.
```

Here is a screenshot of that message:

[image: Error message]

I am not sure why the program is working inside of CLion, but not when trying to run it from file explorer. Is there a solution?

I tried copying some libraries as suggested by solutions to other similar problems. No luck.

Comment: And thoroughly read the [tour], and inform yourself at our [help], what and how you can ask here!

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. But I can make some suggestions for how to improve your question: (1) Do not provide text as images - and [here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365). (2) Provide a [mre] or at least as close as you can reasonably get - to help the community to recreate your issue. (3) Research the problem _before_ you post a question. Show your research so the community does not spend time repeating what you have already tried. For more background info see [ask] and browse related topics in [help].

Comment: This is most likely a dll conflict.

Comment: @guard3 Yes, I am using MinGW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because your application's runtime environment in CLion differs from your application's runtime environment when initiated from Windows File Explorer. In my case I resolved this by getting my CLion environment to reflect the my Windows runtime environment with respect to **MinGW**.

CLion comes bundled with its own version of **MinGW**, which you can see if you go to **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains > MinGW (default)**:

[image: toolchains1]

In my case the actual path for *Bundled MinGW* was under **C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\231.8109.222\bin\cmake...** which would not be known in your Windows environment by default. You can either update your CLion setting to reflect that of your Windows environment, or vice versa. I chose to update my CLion setting.

In my case I was already using a [WinLibs standalone build of GCC and MinGW-w64 for Windows](https://winlibs.com/) which I had unzipped to a directory named **C:\Winlibs**, and had the directory **C:\WinLibs\mingw64** as part of my **PATH** environment variable, so I just updated **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains > MinGW (default)** to reflect that, by clicking the folder icon on the **Toolset** field:

[image: toolchains2]

Then if you rebuild your project you should see that the *External Libraries* for your project have changed to reflect the new **Toolset** value:

[image: Externals]

Rerun your project to verify that it still works within CLion. If so, you can then rerun your project directly in Windows, and it should work because the MinGW dependencies will be found on your **PATH**.

Notes:

- I could not reproduce your specific error ("_...*ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located...*") because you didn't provide any details about your project or your Windows environment. But the larger issue stands regardless: ensure that your CLion and Windows runtime environments match.
- I tested using a simple "*Hello World!*" C++ application. If you still have problems, try creating a trivial new project (**File > New Project > C++ Executable**), and update your question if that also fails. That approach also makes it easy for others to attempt to reproduce and diagnose your problem.
- Rather than running your application from File Explorer, try running it from the **Command Prompt**. That way the window remains open after the application completes.
- You don't have to use **WinLibs** as your source for **MinGW** if you don't already have it. See the [Pre-built toolchains and packages available here](https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/#winlibscom) for alternatives.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I had MinGW already installed and didn't realize that Clion came bundled along with its own version of MinGW. 
Changing the Toolset field, as you suggested, worked perfectly. Thank you very much!